# Creating a flowchart in HTML

Tags: html, css, flowchart

I am a complete noob in CSS/HTML and have been trying to create a flowchart for a few hours now with little success.I'm trying to create something similar to this:
http://jsfiddle.net/pointbypointuk/ETg7q/2/

However I only want 2 of the subheadings, not 4.

How would I go about creating this? I cant seem to get anything to line up as it should.

Even better, is there a free software/library that allows you to create a flowchart by drawing it and then just convert it into code?

Answer (score 14):

You might want to take a look at this http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree